# Use Blender2.8 grease pencil as live texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, grease-pencil

### Is there any way that a stroke object can be used as a 2d texture? (Blender 2.8)

I would like to be able to use my animated stroke, as a texture which I plug into whatever material I want. This could be used for 2d cartoonish facial expressions, which are then wrapped over 3d objects, and used over multiple materials at the same time. Is this possible?

I can already guess that rendering the 2d animation to a movie and importing the said movie and using it as a texture is, in fact, a possible solution. However I find myself desiring something a bit more live, so I can edit strokes and see immediate results. (not to mention the loss of quality when rendering it to a movie and reimporting it)

Edit:
I'm also using cycles

Comment: I want to know the same thing!  To bad this hasn't had much attention.  :(